# Display most recent post on homepage?

Tags: posts, recent-posts

Is there any plugin that allows me to customize my blog homepage to show only most recent post?

Problem is that on my home page, it displays too much posts, my blog is here, http://www.nooranibakerally.net/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin panel, Go to `Settings > Reading` 
and set *Blog pages show at most* to `1` post.